# How to use multiple code to get a result in like statement in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I Have a table in which the uploaded file information is stored as below.

[image]

I have written below query to get the upload result.

```
set @v_stk_code = '50400'; -- 2753,8601
set @v_date = '0619';
set @sas = (Select Count(file_name) from ims_data.batchlog where file_name like concat('%',@v_stk_code ,'%',@v_date,'.txt','%') and file_name like 'SAS%' and upload_status = 'success');
set @product = (Select Count(file_name) from ims_data.batchlog where file_name like concat('%',@v_stk_code ,'%',@v_date,'.txt','%') and file_name like 'P%' and upload_status = 'success');
Select @v_stk_code,
    case 
        when @sas=0 and @product=0 then 'SAS and Product not Uploaded' 
        when @sas>0 and @product>0 then 'SAS and Product is Uploaded' 
        when @sas>0 and @product=0 then 'SAS uploaded but Product File Missing' 
        when @sas=0 and @product>0 then 'Product uploaded but SAS File Missing' 
    end as `Status`;
```

I am getting the result for one stockiest code but I want to get multiple stockiest result which would be provided in the parameter.

Comment: What will your multiple codes in one parameter look like?

Comment: That will be separated by comma ex. 1234,1234,1234,1234

Comment: You cant. Just store the values on a table and do a cross join.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropezza "you can't" - not true. "Do a cross join" - cross joins don't have predicates, probably not what you'd need in this case

Comment: @CaiusJard I mean you can't  do it using a CSV variable.

Answer (score 0):

It might be possible to approach this differently and present the results in a tabular form. given

```
drop table if exists t;
create table t
(id int auto_increment primary key, file_name varchar(100),upload_status varchar(10));

insert into t (file_name,upload_status) values
('p333_0709.txt','fail'),
('p111_0809.txt','success'),
('p111_0809.txt','success'),
('sas111_0809.txt','success'),
('p222_0809.txt','success'),
('sas222_0809.txt',null),
('p333_0809.txt','success'),
('sas222_0809.txt','success');
```

you could use a sub query a (or link table) to specify the products and dates you are interested in and a sub query s to split the filename which can then be left joined from a. The main query could then do some conditional aggregation.

```
select dt,prd,
         sum(case when concat('p',prd) = fileproduct and upload_status = 'success' then 1 else 0 end) ploadedsuccess,
         sum(case when concat('p',prd) = fileproduct and (upload_status is null or upload_status <> 'success') then 1 else 0 end) ploadedfail,
         sum(case when concat('sas',prd) = fileproduct and upload_status = 'success' then 1 else 0 end) sasloadedsuccess,
         sum(case when concat('sas',prd) = fileproduct and (upload_status is null or upload_status <> 'success') then 1 else 0 end) sasloadedfall,
         sum(case when fileproduct is null then 1 else 0 end) 'notloaded'
from
(
(select 111 as prd, '0809' as dt union select 222, '0809' as dt union select 333, '0709' as dt union select 444, '0809' as dt) a

left join
(
select substring_index(file_name,'_',1) fileproduct,
         cast(substring_index(substring_index(file_name,'.',1) ,'_',-1) as int) fileproductdate,
         upload_status
from t) s
on (concat('p',a.prd) = s.fileproduct or concat('sas',a.prd) = s.fileproduct) and
    s.fileproductdate = a.dt
) 
group by dt,prd
```

I don't know your data but it may be possible for there to be 2 p for the matching sas as in p111 trying catch all these types of curiosities as text messages would (in my view) be messy and better tabulated.

```
+------+-----+----------------+-------------+------------------+---------------+-----------+
| dt   | prd | ploadedsuccess | ploadedfail | sasloadedsuccess | sasloadedfall | notloaded |
+------+-----+----------------+-------------+------------------+---------------+-----------+
| 0709 | 333 |              0 |           1 |                0 |             0 |         0 |
| 0809 | 111 |              2 |           0 |                1 |             0 |         0 |
| 0809 | 222 |              1 |           0 |                1 |             1 |         0 |
| 0809 | 444 |              0 |           0 |                0 |             0 |         1 |
+------+-----+----------------+-------------+------------------+---------------+-----------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Note there are some assumptions here for example the filenames have a standard format - mycode doesn't care what the extension is as long as it's there and it does care that there is an _.